# How to use class methods in python?

Tags: python, attributeerror, class-method

I have this code

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  @classmethod
  def from_classmethod(cls, name):
    return cls(name)

p = Person.from_classmethod("Moctar")
p.name
```

But it shows the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What could be going wrong here, or am i using wrongly the python @classmethod feature ?

Comment: `self.name = name` - you have to assign value to create variable `self.name`. If you do only `self.name` then it tries to get value from `self.name` which not exist yet.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce that error. Can you post the code that does?

Answer (score 0):

As @furas says, what I think you want is:

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  @classmethod
  def from_classmethod(cls, name):
    return cls(name)

p = Person.from_classmethod("Moctar")
print(p.name)
```

Result:

```
Moctar
```

It is the assignment to `self.name` that creates that attribute on the instance of Person that you are creating.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is an error HERE but i did the assignment in my local code actually